# How can get a list of running apps android 7 (Nougat)?

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, android-7.1-nougat

At android 6 I get list of running app and process id by accessing to proc file. But at android 7 it’s not working. So any way how can I get running process with process id at android nougat?

Comment: same question! did you find a way? google is setting more and more restrictions. they could have a special permission for that.